# pg_restore fails with missing tablespace eventhough --no-tablespaces is given

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a database into postgres with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_restore.exe" --dbname=postgres --clean --create --format=d --jobs=16 --no-tablespaces --host=localhost --username=postgres "S:\Directory-Dump_Inn"
```

The fine manual says:

> --no-tablespaces
>
> Do not output commands to select tablespaces. With this option, all objects will be created in whichever tablespace is the default during restore.

I thought this means I wouldn't have to create the tablespace, from which the dump orgins. As the import fails with

```
ERROR: tablespace "ts_inn" does not exist
```

I guess, this assumption is wrong. So what does the explanation from the manual mean then?
The import works fine if I create the tablespace beforehand.

Edit: Version of importing server is 9.5.4, version of exporting server is 9.6.3. Probably the export command is important, too:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump.exe" --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format directory --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --compress 0 --jobs 4 --verbose --file "F:\Postgres-Backup\Directory-Dump_Inn" "inn" 2>> %logfile%
```

Is the culprit that the export omits `--no-tablespaces`? If it is and if I added `--no-tablespaces` as an argument to pg_dump, then why would I use `--no-tablespaces` during import? Obviously then there wouldn't be any `CREATE TABLESPACE xxx` in the dump file.

Comment: Despite the fact that `--no-tablespaces` doesn't export `CREATE  TABLESPACE`'s commands, the option `tablespace` stays declared in the database object being exported, and that's where the error come from when you import it in a database that haven't that tablespace.

Comment: So when would one use `--no-tablespaces` then?

Comment: I've "explained" the behavior you are saying, but I did not mention that was possibly a bug, you should upgrade your Postgres installation to a 9.5 stable release and see if the ERROR goes way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem quite like yours was fixed in [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e97e9c57bd22b2dfbfaf41f7d5c69789f7fad554) commit in Sep 2016 to fix [bug #14315](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160908081953.1402.75347@wrigleys.postgresql.org), so make sure that you have PostgreSQL 9.5 or later with the latest patches.

But even with these patches your example will fail, because you didn't add `--no-tablespaces` to the invocation of `pg_dump`.

It is kind of surprising, but to suppress the `TABLESPACE` clause of `CREATE DATABASE` in the dump, it is not enough to call `pg_restore --no-tablespaces`. The dump has to be created with that option.

Comment: For the Postgres version see the updated question. But even after downloading (and using) the latest 10.0 x64 under Windows the result stays the same. The link you provided is targeted towards pg_dump: is my assumption correct that I would have had to `pg_dump` with `--no-tablespaces` (see edited question)?

Comment: It is like this: when using a plain dump (`-Fp`), it is `pg_dump` that inserts the problematic statement. When using the custom format (`-Fc`), it is `pg_restore` that does it. So you'll have to update the importing server version.

Comment: I'm not sure whether a directory dump falls into the plain or custom category. So I made another attempt from Postgres 10 back into Postgres 10 with the two commands described in my question - same result:

`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_restore.exe" --dbname=postgres --create --format=d --jobs=16 --no-tablespaces --host=localhost --username=postgres G:\Postgres-Backup\Directory-Dump_Inn
...

pg_restore: [Archivierer (DB)] could not execute query: FEHLER:  Tablespace Â»ts_innÂ« existiert nicht`

Comment: That's surprising; it works here (even with directory format). Do a `pg_restore --no-tablespaces` without a destination database to get the SQL script and figure out what the command with the tablespace in it is.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_restore.exe" --file=G:\Postgres-Backup\skript_inn.sql --schema-only --create --format=d --jobs=16 --no-tablespaces --host=localhost --username=postgres G:\Postgres-Backup\Directory-Dump_Inn` 

results in:


`-- PostgreSQL database dump

-- Dumped from database version 10.0
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.0
...

CREATE DATABASE inn WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'German_Germany.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'German_Germany.1252' TABLESPACE = ts_inn;` 
Sorry for ugly formatting...

Comment: Oh, now I see the problem. I'll rewrite the answer.